# Stack structrue assembler

Tags: assembly, x86, stack

```
mov ax, 07C0h       ; Set up 4K stack space after this bootloader
add ax, 288         ; (512 + 4096) / 16 = 288
mov ss, ax
mov sp, 4096

mov ax, 07C0h
mov ds, ax
```

I have problem with understanding this code. Is my calculations right in real adresses?

```
cs = 07c0h
ss = 07c0h + 288
sp = 07c0h + 288 + 4096
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is a bootloader (MBR), right?  You didn't say so explicitly, so I just want to make sure.

Comment: Its taken from MikeOS, i.e. work copy of code, I tested.

Comment: That doesn't answer whether it's a boot loader or not.

Comment: Why do a runtime addition of 2 constants?

Comment: Thanks for your interest. Yes, its right - it is a bootloader (MBR) from MikeOS example. Runtime addition of 2 constants? I think it just for education purposes. I not author of this code.

Comment: `cs` has not been set. Did you mean `ds`? If the coder wanted the stack in the code segment, it would be better to `mov ax, cs; mov ss, ax;` And your understanding of segment register addressing is incorrect. The stack pointer is to `((07C0h + 288) << 4) + 4096`. Meaning that the segment registers select a 16-byte paragraph. This results in there being many ways to address the same physical address.

Comment: ... because adding `1` to a segment register has the same effect as adding `16` to an address.

Comment: Thank you, it means sp = 07c0h + (288 * 16) + 4096 ?